# How can i get last checkbox checked value on button click

Tags: jquery

I want to get value of only last checked checkbox on button click, I have used following script but not getting value of last checked checkbox.

1 ) Method

```
    $('#close_btn').click(function(){
    var checkedIds = $(".chkIt:last:checked").each(function() {
            return this.class;
     });
});
    console.log(checkedIds)
```

2 ) Method

```
$('#close_btn').click(function(){
    var checkedIds = $(".chkIt:last:checked").map(function() {
                return this.value;    
    });
});
    console.log(checkedIds)
```

3 ) `var checkedIds1 = $(".chkIt:last:checked").attr('value');`

HTML

```
<table id="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr class="table_header">
    <tr class="product_row">
        <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="85" product_weight="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product_row">
        <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="90" product_weight="22"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: please, post a minimal and reproducible part of your html, then we can have a better idea of how reach the desired goal and understand the checkboxes you have

Comment: if you check and then uncheck a checkbox, the result should be the value of this checkbox or the previous checked checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with [.last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) and [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

`$(".chkIt:checked:last").attr('value')` will also work.

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(".chkIt:checked:last").attr("value"));
  console.log($(".chkIt:checked").last().val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr class="table_header">
    <tr class="product_row">
        <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="85" product_weight="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product_row">
        <td class="small-check SerialNumber"><input class="chkIt" type="checkbox" name="products[product_id][]" value="90" product_weight="22"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<button id="test">test</button>
```

Comment: It's always return 90, Suppose you select second checkbox first and first one is  last then it'll show 85

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value by following code:

```
$(".chkIt:checked:last").val()
```

No need to loop through elements